# Why isn't this generic function supported in my example?

Tags: f#

I'm trying to learn F# and have put together the following code:

```
open System.Collections.Generic

type Version = Version of int
type AggregateId = AggregateId of int

type IEventdata = interface end
type EventMeta = EventMeta of AggregateId * Version
type Event = Event of EventMeta * IEventdata 

type ICommandData = interface end
type CommandMeta = CommandMeta of AggregateId * Version
type Command = CommandMeta * ICommandData

type EventStore = {
    GetEvents : AggregateId -> Event seq;
    Insert : Event seq -> unit
}

let commandDispatcherFactory (mapping: (Command -> Event seq -> Event seq), es: EventStore) =
    (
        fun (command: Command) -> 
            match command with
            | (CommandMeta(aggregateId, version), commandData) ->
                let events = es.GetEvents (aggregateId)
                let resultingEvents = mapping command events
                (es.Insert(resultingEvents))
    )

type DummyCommand = 
    | Command1
    interface ICommandData

type DummyCommand2 = 
    | Command2
    interface ICommandData

type UnsupportedCommand = 
    | Command3

let dummyMapping = (fun ((command, commandData):Command) (events: Event seq) ->
    match commandData with
    | :? DummyCommand as dummyCommand -> 
        (printfn "Handling Command: %A" dummyCommand)
        Seq.empty<Event>
    | :? DummyCommand2 as dummyCommand -> 
        (printfn "Handling Command: %A" dummyCommand)
        Seq.empty<Event>
    | _ -> 
        (printfn "Unsupported command: %A" commandData)
        Seq.empty<Event>
)

let dummyEs = {
    GetEvents = (fun (aggregateId) -> Seq.empty<Event>);
    Insert = (fun (events:Event seq) -> ())
}
dummyMapping (CommandMeta(AggregateId(1),Version(1)), Command1) Seq.empty<Event>
dummyMapping (CommandMeta(AggregateId(1),Version(1)), Command2) Seq.empty<Event> // Why does this work?

let commandDispatcher = commandDispatcherFactory(dummyMapping, dummyEs)
commandDispatcher (CommandMeta(AggregateId(1),Version(1)), Command1)
commandDispatcher (CommandMeta(AggregateId(1),Version(1)), Command2) // this doesn't work
```

I know it might be a wall of text, but I didn't manage to narrow it down. It's the last call to my commandDispatcher that doesn't work, and I can't figure out why. I know there probably are other things to do better, but that is something I'm working on :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a cut down repro:

```
let f x (y:System.IComparable) = ()
let g = f 1

g 3
g "test" // not okay

let g' : System.IComparable -> unit = f 1
g' 3
g' "test" // okay

let g'' x = f 1 x
g'' 3
g'' "test" // okay
```

What happens is that the compiler infers a generic type for `g` (`g:('a -> unit) when 'a :> System.IComparable` in the case of my example).  However, `g` is a syntactic value and therefor can't be generic (see questions about the value restriction), so the compiler needs to pick a specific type.  If you don't use `g` at all, you'll get a compiler error.  If you use it at exactly one concrete type, the compiler will pick that type.  If you use it at more than one type, the compiler will specialize based on the first type used and throw an error after that.

Two workarounds are to either annotate with a non-generic type or to eta-expand so that `g` isn't a syntactic value.

Answer (score 3):

The compiler is specializing the type of `commandDispatcher` based on the initial usage. You can fix it with a cast:

```
commandDispatcher (CommandMeta(AggregateId(1),Version(1)), Command1 :> ICommandData)
commandDispatcher (CommandMeta(AggregateId(1),Version(1)), Command2) //works
```